# How to extract table, convert it to data frame ,write as csv file and deal with child tables?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I cant write the file as a csv. file there is an error, as I want to Extract bike sharing system data from a Wiki page and convert the data to a data frame. but When I use the head function to see the table or str. function I cant determine the table it came out with so many unorganized details.

Also Note that this HTML page at least contains three child  nodes under the root HTML node. So, you will need to use (html_nodes(root_node, "table") function to get all its child  nodes:

```
<html>
   <table>(table1)</table>
   <table>(table2)</table>
  <table>(table3)</table>
  ...
 </html>


     url<- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems"
     root_node<-read_html(url)
    table_nodes <- html_nodes(root_node,"table")

     Bicycle_sharing <- html_table(table_nodes, fill = TRUE )

 head(Bicycle_sharing)

 summary(Bicycle_sharing)
 str(Bicycle_sharing)

 ## Exporting the date frame as csv. file.

 write.csv(mtcars,"raw_bike_sharing_systems.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

data <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems" %>% 
  read_html() %>%  
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(2) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

data %>%
  write_csv(file = "bike_sharing.csv")
```